# Java beginner baffled by "<identifier> expected" error

Tags: java, identifier

I've googled until I'm cross-eyed, but I guess this is a pretty generic error. I keep simplifying my code to try to narrow it down.

```
class ListMaker {  
  public int testMe() {
    return 0;
  }
} 

class Examples {
  Examples() {};
  int testInt;
  testInt = ListMaker.testMe(); <--- compiler error: <identifier> expected
}
```

Comment: It's not really a very generic error - it's almost *always* caused by people including statements directly in a class declaration when they should be putting that code in a method or constructor.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that explanation. But testMe is a method and there is nothing else in the ListMaker class at this point. And I've checked for missing semicolons.

Comment: It's the statement *calling* `testMe` which is the problem. Look at it - it's an assignment statement. Which method or constructor is it in? It's not - it's directly in the class declaration. That's the (first) problem. (The next problem is that you're calling it as if it's a static method, when it's actually an instance method.) Did you read the duplicate question that I linked to? (The link is at the top of the page.)

Comment: Okay, I think I see. The problem isn't in ListMaker, it's because I try to call ListMaker.testMe() outside of a method. Thanks for the help.